# Odoo 10 python array list call element

Tags: python, arraylist, odoo-10

```
@api.depends('employee_id')
    def create_employee_report(self):
        count = 0
        employee_array = []
        employee_data = {}
        for employee in self.env['hr.employee'].search([]):
            if employee.socialsecurityno:
                count = count + 1
                employee_data ={'count':str(count),'sicil_no':employee.socialsecurityno}
                employee_array.append(employee_data)
                print employee_array
                print employee_array[0][count]
```

How can i call the element?

```
 employee_array[0].count
```

or

```
 employee_array[0[count]]
```

i tried all combinations but it is not working. 
Thank you.

Comment: what error comes in when you RUN the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'print employee_array[0]["count"]' as 'count' is a key of your dictionary. If you don't keep it in quotes python assumes that it is a variable. And I assume you always want to print the 0th element from your array as per your code.

An example snippet of what is happening inside for loop:

```
>>> employee_array = []
>>> employee_data ={'count':"1",'sicil_no':"9704"}
>>> employee_array.append(employee_data)
>>> print employee_array
[{'count': '1', 'sicil_no': '9704'}]
>>> print employee_array[0]["count"]
1
>>> employee_data ={'count':"2",'sicil_no':"9705"}
>>> employee_array.append(employee_data)
>>> print employee_array
[{'count': '1', 'sicil_no': '9704'}, {'count': '2', 'sicil_no': '9705'}]
>>> print employee_array[0]["count"]
1
```

OR may be you are looking for:

```
>>> print employee_array[count]
```

and not:

```
>>> print employee_array[0]["count"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use print employee_array[count]["count"] :exemple

```
 for employee in self.env['hr.employee'].search([]):
            if employee.socialsecurityno:
                count = count + 1
                employee_data = {'count':str(count),'sicil_no':employee.socialsecurityno}
                employee_array.append(employee_data)
                print employee_array

               print employee_array[count]["count"]
```

to print each item in  employee_array